# Traditional: 菸 vs. 煙?

Tags: traditional-characters

My IME always suggests both 菸 and 煙 for traditional 烟, which makes me think that they're interchangeable. Characters usually are not just simply exchangeable between themselves though.

What nuances exist between 菸 and 煙?

Comment: [A comprehensive summary](http://163.17.243.1/site4/table/13.htm) (if you can read Chinese)

Comment: tobacco plant vs smoke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @YuiTo Cheng 's [link](http://163.17.243.1/site4/table/13.htm)

煙:

- The gas produced when a substance burns. Examples: cooking smoke,soot.
- The black ash condensed by the smoke produced by the burning of things which is often used to make ink.
- Moisture, like water between mountains and rivers. Examples : clouds,  smoke.
- Especially opium. Examples: opium smoke.

菸:

- A plant name. Solanaceae, an annual herb. Its leaf is the material for making cigarettes.

**Conclusion:**

Related to tobacco, use "菸"

Such as: cigarettes, tobacco, tobacco leaves, tobacco wine. "香菸、菸草、菸葉、菸酒"

Related to opium and drugs, or burning something without cigarette, use "煙"

Such as: smoking halls, smoke ghosts, smoke poisons, clouds.
"煙館、煙鬼、煙毒、雲煙"

Answer (score 0):

http://163.17.243.1/site4/table/13.htm
Here is a link in traditional Chinese shows the detailed meaning of these two.

Comment: You should at least quote the relevant information from the link, if the link dies one day your answer will be meaningless.